array based filter over object method in javascript
// this is the input. need to iterate the tech based name from object
let obj=[
        {
        name:"Nithesh",
        tech:["HTML","CSS","JAVA","JS"],
        },
        {
        name:"hari",
        tech:["NodeJS","CSS","React","JS"],
        },
        {
        name:"sathish",
        tech:["Angular","CSS","React","HTML"],
        }
    ]

//and output like this. but I tried all ways but code is not working
o/p={
    "HTML":["Nithesh","sathish"],
    "CSS":["Nithesh","hari", "sathish"],
    "JS":["Nithesh","hari"],
    "React":["hari", "sathish"],
    "NodeJs":["hari"],
    "Angular":["sathish"],
    "JAVA":["Nithesh"],
    }


Please [edit] your question to provide more details on what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. This will help readers figure out what didn’t work and how to answer your question accordingly.

nested loop and check if key alraey exists in the object. if not set the key with empty array and push the name. if exists directly push the name

What code is not working? Add your code attempt to the question.

You can try this.


// Define the input array of objects
let obj = [
    {
        name: "Nithesh",
        tech: ["HTML", "CSS", "JAVA", "JS"],
    },
    {
        name: "hari",
        tech: ["NodeJS", "CSS", "React", "JS"],
    },
    {
        name: "sathish",
        tech: ["Angular", "CSS", "React", "HTML"],
    }
];

// Initialize an empty output object
let output = {};

// Iterate over each object in the input array
obj.forEach(person => {
    // Iterate over each technology in the current person's tech array
    person.tech.forEach(tech => {
        // Check if the technology is already a key in the output object
        if (!output[tech]) {
            // If not, create a new array for this technology
            output[tech] = [];
        }
        // Add the person's name to the array for this technology
        output[tech].push(person.name);
    });
});

// Print the output object to the console
console.log(output);




awesome .its working. thanks for your effort

I would do it with Set, flat, reduce, filter, map and includes. The Set is an optimization to not iterate over duplicate languages.


const obj = [
  {
    name: "Nithesh",
    tech: ["HTML", "CSS", "JAVA", "JS"],
  },
  {
    name: "hari",
    tech: ["NodeJS", "CSS", "React", "JS"],
  },
  {
    name: "sathish",
    tech: ["Angular", "CSS", "React", "HTML"],
  },
];
const res = [...new Set(obj.map((item) => item.tech).flat())].reduce(
  (acc = {}, item, index) => {
    acc[item] = obj
      .filter((personData) => personData.tech.includes(item))
      .map((personData) => personData.name);
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(res);




awesome .its working. thanks for your effort

Iterate over the outer and inner arrays to find the pairs you need, and then create a new property in the result object in case you find a new language (in tech), and always append the current name to the array you have for that property:


// Your example input:
const arr=[{name:"Nithesh",tech:["HTML","CSS","JAVA","JS"],},{name:"hari",tech:["NodeJS","CSS","React","JS"],},{name:"sathish",tech:["Angular","CSS","React","HTML"],}];

const result = {};
for (const {name, tech} of arr) {
    for (const lang of tech) (result[lang] ??= []).push(name);
}
console.log(result);




awesome .its working. thanks for your effort
